# Batch Script - Call a subroutine for each token

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am trying to pass a token to a subroutine in batch script-

```
SET devices=host1 host2 host3
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=," %%G IN (%devices%) DO CALL :sendReq %%G

:sendReq

curl.exe http://%1:1234/service/monitor

GOTO :EOF
```

Problems -
`The system cannot find the file host1` - is the error message not sure why.

`%1` is not resolving to `host1`?

Comment: @Mat. Thank you for the edit. Will do that from next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`for /f` is really meant to parse text files or commands, and parses them one whole line at a time. Look at what this produces:

```
SET devices=host1 host2 host3
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ("%devices%") DO call :sendReq %%G %%H %%I
goto :EOF

:sendReq
echo Parm1: %1
echo Parm2: %2
echo Parm3: %3
GOTO :EOF
```

(i.e. each go through the loop reads one whole line, and assigns the different tokens to `%G`, then `%H`, `%I`, `%J`, ... depending on how many tokens you actually have.)

You just need the simpler version of `for`:

```
SET devices=host1 host2 host3
FOR %%G IN (%devices%) DO call :sendReq %%G
goto :EOF

:sendReq
echo In sendReq: %1
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. 2 follow-up questions:

1. When passing the %devices% as a parameter `host1 host2` the `FOR` is executing for 3 times - may be because of the carriage return? How can that be avoided?

2. There are some temp files generated as part of the script, as the code hits `goto :eof` the clean-up is not happening. How to get the files cleaned up only after the execution of last token ?

Thanks again.

Comment: Do the cleanup just after the for. As for 1., make sure your vars a clean, or skip invalid input in `sendReq`. (Or use another scripting language :) )